# Initially selected item in MAUI CollectionView isn't highlighted

Tags: ios, maui, collectionview

I'm programmatically initializing the selection of an item in a CollectionView before rendering it. On iOS, the UI shows nothing selected when the CollectionView is first rendered even though I bind SelectedItem to the property that is programmatically initialized to point to one of the CollectionView items. After I click on an item, the selection of items works as expected. This all works as I expect on Android.

Here is my simple ViewModel for reproducing this issue:

```
namespace CollectionViewRepro
{
    public partial class CollectionViewData : ObservableObject
    {
        public List<string> CollectionViewElements { get; private set; }

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string selected;

        public CollectionViewData()
        {
            CollectionViewElements = new()
            {
                " 1 ",
                " 2 ",
                " 3 "
            };

            Selected = CollectionViewElements[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:collectionviewrepro="clr-namespace:CollectionViewRepro"
             x:DataType="collectionviewrepro:CollectionViewData"
             x:Class="CollectionViewRepro.MainPage">

    <VerticalStackLayout
        Margin="10,30,10,0"
        HorizontalOptions="Center">

        <Label Text="Sample Label - Centered" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionViewElements}" HorizontalOptions="Center" SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}" HeightRequest="20">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
         </CollectionView>

        <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Label Text="This is the selected item: "/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Selected}"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>


    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the code-behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private CollectionViewData vm { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        vm = new CollectionViewData();
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

Here is what the initial rendering looks like on an Android emulator:

[image]

On an iPhone emulator:

[image]

Note that the text below the CollectionView in the iOS image verifies that the Selected property does point to "2" when the page is rendered, but the 2 in the CollectionView isn't highlighted. If I click on any of the items, it is then highlighted and "This is the selected item:" shows the correct item. So, I know the Selected property is being defined properly and the TwoWay Binding of the CollectionView SelectedItem is working properly.

This definitely seems like a bug to me, however, I'd love to hear different perspectives or suggested workarounds. I've thought about giving Syncfusion's ListView a go.

Please forgive this very brief rant... I'm getting quite frustrated and discouraged by the continuous stream of bugs and inconsistencies across Android and iOS that have delayed my releases by many weeks.

Comment: It's a duplicate thread referring to [selecteditem-of-a-collectionview-is-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75593079/programmatically-setting-the-selecteditem-of-a-collectionview-is-not-working-on/75598722#75598722), you can check it for details.