# Color for SelectedItem of CollectionView not set when SelectedItem is assigned in ViewModel

Tags: maui

I have a .NET MAUI App in which I us a `CustomPopup` from the CommunityToolkit. When it opens, I have a `CollectionView` with `ObservableProperties` that Bind to it.

There is also a `SelectedItem` Binding on the `CollectionView` to its ViewModel.

I also set a `VisualStateGroup` to specify the Color for a selected item:

```xml
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource LightOrange2}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

When I do set the `SelectedSavedStore` in in the ViewModel I can only see the Color set on **Android**, but not on **iOS**:

**Android:**

[image]

**iOS:**

[image]

Right now, I think it is a Bug and wrote the following isse:

https://github.com/MAUIoxo/SelectedItemColorNotSet_20030

But, I am also not sure if this is a Bug or if I am doing something stupid here and just Android still accepts it.

Would it be possible to have some more eyes on it to be save for that?

The ContentPage with the correpsonding Bindings is located in:
`..\Pages\Views\Controls\CustomPicker\CustomPopupContentPage.xaml.cs`

My corresponding ViewModel is located in:
`..\ViewModels\CustomPopupViewModel.cs`
The selecttion is done in `SelectSavedStoreByName(..)` with `SelectedSavedStore = foundSavedStore;`

Am I doing something wrong here?

**Hint:**

- I am working with iPhone 14 Pro Max on iOS 16.2 in the corresponding Simulator

Comment: That’s what I always do. I am working on iPhone 14 Pro Max with 16.2. I normally also clean everything on Mac, too. But the selected item is not in the selected item color unless I click on an item. When it is just opened it is not in selected Color :(

Comment: I misunderstood your question at first. After I dig into it, I can reproduce your question. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I agree with you. I can reproduce your issue.

After searching on GitHub, seems related to [[iOS] CollectionView multi-select pre-selected item VisualState error #13072](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13072) and [Custom selection styles for items in CollectionView are ignored when programmatically selecting an item #18933](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18933). You may follow up this issue.

After debugging, I found that the value of `SelectedSavedStore` has been set correctly but UI doesn't update.

So, I come up with a workaround (but in a little awkward way).

```
    private async void OnDropDownButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        customPickerPopup = new CustomPopup();

        //Here we first set the SelectedSavedStore to null
        SavedStore selected = customPopupViewModel.SelectedSavedStore;
        customPopupViewModel.SelectedSavedStore = null;
        customPickerPopup.BindingContext = customPopupViewModel;

        ...
        //And after a delay, we set it back to the right value
        mainPage.ShowPopupAsync(customPickerPopup);
        await Task.Delay(50);
        
        customPopupViewModel.SelectedSavedStore = selected;
        customPopupViewModel.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSavedStore");
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great finding! Question to the Delay, should we use it or is it kind of mandatory here for reasons?

Comment: Umm... It's just a workaround not a final solution but I admit it's an awkward way. I was inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75593079/programmatically-setting-the-selecteditem-of-a-collectionview-is-not-working-on). Using Task.Delay should be careful with Deadlock. And how much time to delay is also a question, which may depend on device performance. Hoping this issue can be fixed as soon as possible.